# Azure blob with anonymous read access and private endpoint

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

we have the following scenario

1. we have an api running in a azure app service, which accesses file in a blob container that has anonymous read access enabled, all is working well.

now our requirement is to move the app service and storage account into a vnet with private endpoints.

Questions

1. once we move both of these into a VNET will the app service be able to access the blob container anonymously ?  the third party library that we are using needs anonymous access to this blob, so that it parse and do its job.

Thanks -nen

Comment: Please let us know what is third party library ?is any public DLL which try to access. Anonymous access to the blob with private endpoint is that  are you looking? Please  elaborate  your question with more details.

Comment: yes Anonymous access to the blob with private endpoint is what i am looking for, basically the thirdparty dll, takes a url and downloads the file, that's it.  What we want to make sure is,  with "Anynomous Access" enabled,  with a private endpoint only the appservice (dll) should be able to access it, no one else over the internet.

Comment: Yes, if the calls are coming via that specific IP only, then it should ideally allow
because it's  check the IP address first and then auth happens.
The Authorization header and restricting the storage to specific network both are different